# Display text of just the element clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to click on a div, show the text within it, then when clicking on another div, hide all the other text in other divs and show the text in the clicked div.

Code here

http://jsfiddle.net/Refxq/140/

```
<div class="myClass"><span>First</span></div>
<div class="myClass"><span>Second</span></div>
<div class="myClass"><span>Third</span></div>

.myClass{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:2px;
}
.myClass span{
  display:none;
}

$(".myClass").click(function() {
  // Hide all item spans
  $(".myClass span").hide();
  // Show the element next to this
  $(this).first().show();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work : [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankittyagi/Refxq/141/)

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {
  // Hide all item spans
  $(".myClass span").hide();
  // Show the element next to this
  $(this).find('span').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `.find('span')` to get child span:

```
$(this).find('span').show();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Refxq/142/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
use .find in Jquery;  the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. 

$(this).find('span').show();

or .has() in jquery Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

$(this).has('span').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function to exclude the item you wish to show from the hiding process.

```
$(".myClass").on('click', function () {
    // Store a reference to the element we want to show
    var shownElement = $(this).find('span');
    // Ensure 'shownElement' is shown
    shownElement.show();
    // Hide everything apart from 'shownElement'
    $(".myClass span").not(shownElement).hide();
});
```

**[See this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jA8RR/)**

Answer (score 0):

You mean accordion.. just have a look at this [jquery plugin](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). its easy..

or if thruegh code..

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {
  $(".myClass span").css('display','none');
  $(this).find('span').css('display','block');
});
```